# Is there a way to keep a top N list with Redis?

Tags: redis

I work with a MongoDB connection and have a Redis Elastic Cache at hand. There's a Mongo collection which essentially changes a few times per week and it includes a `totalPoints` for which I'd like to sort some or even all of them, this collection has a huge number of records.

So, *sorting* demands much work to DB, I really can't pretend to order them at a query, so I'd like to have a TOP list.

I would like to get way to push records, either srtings or objects and order them as a bucket of max size n for the top of those.

Comment: Read about Redis' Sorted Sets - you can use these to store the records (or "pointers" to the records) sorted by `totalPoints`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pattern described by anitrez here : http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/take-advantage-of-redis-adding-it-to-your-stack.html

Basically just use a sorted set and add the collection values with score as totalPoints.

```
zadd toplist totalPoints <collectionItemIdentifier>
```

Then fetch top 100 as

```
ZREVRANGE toplist 0 99
```

You can keep the size in check (it should not be required) by periodically using `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` and remove elements whose score is in a certain range.

Check http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set for more information and commands available on sorted set.